# XMLHttpRequest - append php function to .json?add_fields ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, silverstripe

I am trying to update someone else's code, which uses a XMLHttpRequest setup to get product information from the server for use on some SilverStripe templates. I want to grab the url() function from Product.php so I can use it to get the url for the Product data object and send it to Google Analytics. However, simply appending it to the existing add_fields data does not work--the url function does not get retrieved.

I'm not very familiar with XMLHttpRequests so I'm kind of clueless as to what to do here.

Here is the JavaScript code that is getting the product data:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var productCatalogService = (function() {
        var endpoint = "/api/v1/Product/";

        return {
            'getProductById': function(id, callback) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', endpoint + id + ".json?add_fields=NutritionalInformationLabelURL,SortOrder,BeautyShotURL,url,Recipe"); //url function is not grabbed
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        callback && callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                    }
                    else {
                        console.error('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
                    }
                };
                xhr.send();
            }
        };
    })();

    var utils = (function() {
        return {
            'removeClass': function(node, className) {
                node.className = node.className.replace(className, '');
                return node;
            },
            'addClass': function(node, className) {
                node.className = node.className.replace(className, '');
                node.className += " " + className;
            },
            'hasClass': function(node, className) {
                return node.className.indexOf(className) >= 0;
            }
        }
    })();

    var changeProduct = function(product) {

        var name = document.querySelector('.product-name'),
            subname = document.querySelector('.product-subname'),
            tagline = document.querySelector('.product-tagline'),
            description = document.querySelector('.product-description'),
            beautyShot = document.querySelector('.beauty-shot'),
            nutritionFacts = document.querySelector('.ingredients-list'),
            mobileNutritionLabel = document.querySelector('.mobile-nutrition-label img'),
            nutritionLabel = document.querySelector('.nutritional-label img'),
            recipeName = document.querySelector('.recipe-name'),
            recipeDescription = document.querySelector('.recipe-description'),
            recipeContainer = document.querySelector('.recipe-container');

        name.innerHTML = product.Name;
        subname.innerHTML = product.SubName;
        description.innerHTML = product.Description;
        tagline.innerHTML = product.Tagline;
        beautyShot.src = product.BeautyShotURL;
        if(product.NutritionalInformationLabelURL){
            nutritionLabel.src = product.NutritionalInformationLabelURL;
            mobileNutritionLabel.src = product.NutritionalInformationLabelURL;
        }

        if(product.NutritionFacts){
            nutritionFacts.innerHTML = product.NutritionFacts;
            if(utils.hasClass(nutritionFacts, 'hidden')) {
                utils.removeClass(nutritionFacts, 'hidden');
            }
        } else {
            utils.addClass(nutritionFacts, 'hidden');
        }


       // var pagePath = product.url();

        console.log(product.url); //returns undefined
        typeof(ga) !== "undefined" &&  ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'page': location.pathname, //want to use the url() function in Product.php here
            'title': product.PageTitle
        });
    };

    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    var products = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-products .product');
    products.forEach(function(product) {
        product.onclick = function() {
            var productId = product.getAttribute('data-product-id');

            productCatalogService.getProductById(productId, function(product) {
                console.log(product);
                changeProduct(product); //add recipe data to be pulled in here (fields are above)
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Product.php

```
<?php
class Product extends DataObject implements Pageable, Searchable {
    private static $api_access = true;

    private static $db = [
        'Name' => 'varchar(255)',
        'SubName' => 'varchar(255)',
        'Tagline' => 'varchar(255)',
        'Description' => 'HTMLText',
        'WhereToBuy' => 'varchar(500)', // external link
        'NutritionFacts' => 'HTMLText',
        'PageTitle'             => 'varchar(250)',
        'MetaKeywords'          => 'Text',
        'MetaDescription'       => 'Text',
        'SortOrder'             =>'Int'
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
        'BeautyShot' => 'Image',
        'ThumbImage' => 'Image',
        'NutritionalInformationLabel' => 'Image',
        'Category' => 'Category',
    ];

    private static $summary_fields = [
        'GridThumbnail' => 'Photo',
        'Name' => 'Name'
    ];

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',  new TextField("Name", "Name"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',  new TextField("SubName", "SubName"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',  new TextField("Tagline", "Tagline"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new HtmlEditorField("Description", "Description"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField("WhereToBuy", "WhereToBuy"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new HtmlEditorField("NutritionFacts", "NutritionFacts"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new UploadField("BeautyShot", "BeautyShot"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new UploadField("ThumbImage", "ThumbImage"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new UploadField("NutritionalInformationLabel", "NutritionalInformationLabel"));

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.SEO',  new TextField("PageTitle", "PageTitle"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.SEO',  new TextareaField("MetaKeywords", "MetaKeywords"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.SEO',  new TextareaField("MetaDescription", "MetaDescription"));
        $fields->removeByName('SortOrder');

        return $fields;
    }

    public function getGridThumbNail() {
        if ($this->BeautyShot()->exists()) {
            return $this->BeautyShot()->SetWidth(100);
        }

        return '(no image)';
    }

    public function getBeautyShotURL() {
        return $this->BeautyShot()->URL;
    }

    public function getNutritionalInformationLabelURL() {
        if ($this->NutritionalInformationLabel()->Exists()) {
            return $this->NutritionalInformationLabel()->URL;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public function getCouponImageURL() {
        if ($this->CouponImage()->Exists()) {
            return $this->CouponImage()->URL;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public function getProductFullName(){
        return $this->Name." ".$this->SubName;

    }

    public function AbsoluteLink() {
        return Director::absoluteURL($this->url());
    }

    private function url() {
        return sprintf("/home/products/%s/%s", $this->Category()->slug(), $this->slug());
    }

    // lifted from Artisa
    public function MetaTags() {
        $tags = "";

        $generator = trim(Config::inst()->get('SiteTree', 'meta_generator'));
        if (!empty($generator)) {
            $tags .= "<meta name=\"generator\" content=\"" . Convert::raw2att($generator) . "\" />\n";
        }

        $charset = Config::inst()->get('ContentNegotiator', 'encoding');
        $tags .= "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=$charset\" />\n";
        if($this->MetaDescription) {
            $tags .= "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"" . Convert::raw2att($this->MetaDescription) . "\" />\n";
        }
        if($this->MetaKeywords) {
            $tags .= "<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"" . Convert::raw2att($this->MetaKeywords) . "\" />\n";
        }

        if(Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_CMSMain')
            && in_array('CMSPreviewable', class_implements($this))
            && !$this instanceof ErrorPage
            && $this->ID > 0
        ) {
            $tags .= "<meta name=\"x-page-id\" content=\"{$this->ID}\" />\n";
            $tags .= "<meta name=\"x-cms-edit-link\" content=\"" . $this->CMSEditLink() . "\" />\n";
        }

        $this->extend('MetaTags', $tags);

        return $tags;
    }

    public function canView($member = null){
        return true;
    }

    public function canEdit($member = null) {
        return true;
    }

    public function canCreate($member = null) {
        return true;
    }

    public function slug()
    {
        return Utilities::friendlyName($this->Name);
    }

    public function Link()
    {
        return $this->url();
    }

    public function getTitleFields() {
        return ['Name', 'SubName'];
    }

    public function getContentFields() {
        return ['Description'];
    }

    public static function getSearchFilter() {
        return [];
    }
}

// Handles Products and categories
class ProductCsvBulkImporter extends CsvBulkLoader {
    protected function processRecord($record, $columnMap, &$results, $preview = false) {
        $categoryName = $record['Main Category'];
        $productName = $record['Product ID'];
        $productSubName = $record['Product Type'];
        $productTagline = $record['Product Label'];
        $productDescription = $record['Product Description'];
        $productKeywords = $record['Keyphrase'];

        $category = Category::get()
            ->filter(['Name' => $categoryName])
            ->first();

        if (!$category) {
            $category = new Category();
            $category->Name = $categoryName;
            $category->write();
        }

        $product = Product::get()
            ->filter(['Name' => $productName])
            ->first();

        if (!$product) {
            $product = new Product();
        }

        $product->PageTitle = sprintf("%s %s", $productName, $productSubName);
        $product->Name = $productName;
        $product->SubName = $productSubName;
        $product->Tagline = $productTagline;
        $product->Description = $productDescription;
        $product->MetaKeywords = $productKeywords;
        $product->CategoryID = $category->ID;
        $product->write();
        return $product->ID;
    }
}
```

I don't know if the code, as it's setup now, is best practice or not as I didn't make it, so if there are mistakes, I can't tell for sure.

Is there some way to append the url() function from Product.php to the .json?add_fields ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the `Product` class, the `url()` method it's `private`, so you don't have access to it outside that class:

```
private function url() {
    return sprintf("/home/products/%s/%s", $this->Category()->slug(), $this->slug());
}
```

If you change that to:

```
public function url() {
    return sprintf("/home/products/%s/%s", $this->Category()->slug(), $this->slug());
}
```

it'll probably work... That's all I can say based on the code you submitted. You should know, there's probably a reason why that `url()` method is private - most probably it's only used internally in the `Product` class.

If it's still not working, try to duplicate that function like this:

```
public function getUrl() {
    return sprintf("/home/products/%s/%s", $this->Category()->slug(), $this->slug());
}
```

...and then in the JS code you can use it like this:

```
console.log(product.Url);
```

As you can see, you have calls like this in the JS code: `product.BeautyShotURL`, but the actual method in the `Product` class it's called `getBeautyShotURL()`, so it should work with `product.Url` (this might also work tough: `product.getUrl`)

Comment: If for some reason, you can't or you're not allowed to change the code in Product.php let me know, and I'll show you how to extend the Product class's functionality by adding a new getUrl() method into a new class (called a DataExtension class).